# How to make a C console app wait before exiting?

Tags: c, console-application

It seems that I can't find any solution to this problem, so I'm asking you. C doesn't support iostream and Console.Readkey unless i did something wrong, so please help!

Comment: Why would you like to do this? The wast majority of console programs _shall_ exit without an additional user input. And never ever insist of keyboard input.

Answer (score 2):

##### C

```c
 getc(stdin);
```

##### C++

```cpp
std::cin.get();
```

##### Worst Example Listed on Many Websites

```c
system("pause"); //never use this
```

[See what's wrong with `system("pause");`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()` or `getc(stdin)` to read a character.  The console is line buffered by default (at least on Linux) so it means it will wait for `enter`.

Answer (score 0):

import this at the top of your code:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

then you can use:

```
sleep()
```

in the brackets you can write for how many seconds do you want your program to pause!

Hope this helps (although Im 3 months late)

Comment: Windows `Sleep`s for milliseconds and Unix `sleep`s for seconds. So your late answer is not correct.